# Best practice to store link to Amazon S3 object on local DB

Tags: sql-server, amazon-s3

I have an application that uses SQL Server to store info about Amazon S3 objects stored.

So we store in the local DB table:

- filename
- size
- mime type
- creation date
- amazon s3 location

We however still want to know if there is any best practice to store the links to Amazon S3 objects.

Appreciate any advice.

Answer (score 0):

You can use Amazon [Simple DB](https://aws.amazon.com/simpledb/) store the info, that way all the of it is accessible within Amazon. For example with the python [boto API](http://boto.readthedocs.org/en/latest/) you would do something like this:

```
import boto.sdb

conn = boto.sdb.connect_to_region('us-west-2')
conn.create_domain('s3-metadata')

sdb_domain = conn.get_domain('s3-metadata')

object_name = 'my_object_name'
object_attrs = {'size': 223424, 'filename': 'myfilename', 'creation_date': '20140325'}

sdb_domain.put_attributes(object_name, object_attrs)
```